# asp.net mvc rasor @raw does not accept <br>

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, razorengine

I have a solution that uses asp.net web api to convert data to pdf.
I am using `@Raw` to display the data in a html formatted manner. But the problem is that if the json string contains the html `<br>` it throws an error. Once I change it manually to XHTML `<br/>` it works fine. 
Why can't @Raw handle html breaks 
? Is there a better way to handle html tags?

Description
     @Raw(@Model.Description)

Comment: Do you get an error with @Raw() or with the json string? @Raw() should have no issues with <br> ...

Comment: it is with @Raw() that I get the error. I used jquery to change the   <br> to <br/>

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons, `Raw` method is not recommended for using - it does not encode input string. The better solution, especially when you already use Web API, would be to just return the non-formatted data, and do the html formatting on the client-side, maybe using some templates library.